# How to smoothly scroll horizontally with ref scrollLeft in React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-hooks, scroll

I'm coding an horizontal slider in React and would like, **onClick**, to slide using **useRef** and **scrollLeft**, it works but I can't seem to make a smooth animation like with the scrollTo behaviour.

here's the working function I have :

```
const scrollX = (direction = 'right') => {
    if (sliderRef.current) {
      const { clientWidth } = sliderRef.current

      direction === 'right'
        ? (sliderRef.current.scrollLeft += clientWidth)
        : (sliderRef.current.scrollLeft -= clientWidth)
    }
  }
```

There's no option

```
behavior: 'smooth'
```

I tried in CSS to add

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

and it doesn't work either

Is it possible or do I need to use another method ?

I couldn't find anything on stackOverflow about scrollLeft specifically, I hope someone can help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) to scroll vertically, horizontally, or both:

```
const { clientWidth, scrollLeft } = sliderRef.current

element.scrollTo({
  left: scrollLeft + clientWidth,
  behavior: "smooth",
});
```